# Laravel and Arabic slugs

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

When creating a slug from a name, the slug is in English letters.

Example:

name = مقالة جديدة

slug = mk-l-gdyd

It should be: مقالة-جديدة

Any idea how to solve this issue? I'm using [this package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable).

**Model**

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasSlug;

    protected $primarykey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'slug', 'body',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    public function getSlugOptions(): SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('title')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it, Laravel only support some language to generate slug : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/064c0c8a0ad8e341f5b9b94ac03752e5e3cfaabb/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L737

Answer (score 1):

The [spatie/laravel-sluggable package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable/blob/master/README.md) uses the Laravel `Str::slug()` helper to generate the slug, which can take a third parameter for language if a character has a different transliterations depending on the original language used.  To use this with the Spatie package, add `usingLanguage('ar')` to your method chain.

> To set the language used by Str::slug you may call usingLanguage

```php
public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
{
    return SlugOptions::create()
        ->generateSlugsFrom('title')
        ->saveSlugsTo('slug')
        ->usingLanguage('ar');
}
```

However please note that the entire purpose of this method is to produce "SEO-friendly" slugs by *transliterating* into ASCII (i.e. Western alphabet only), and **will not preserve any non-ASCII characters**.

As a side note, even Yoast SEO [isn't sure what to do](https://youtu.be/xhRTOHXmx4U) with non-ASCII slugs.  In the meantime, the simplest approach would be to use `preg_replace()` to strip punctuation and convert whitespace to hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following

```
dump($stringParts = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", 'مقالة جديدة'))));

$slug = '';
foreach ($stringParts as $key =>  $string) {
    $hyphen = ($key < sizeof($stringParts) - 1) ? '-' : '';
    $slug .= $string . $hyphen;
}

dd($slug);
// "مقالة-جديدة"
```

[Check Working Demo](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/DefensiveSandybrownBash)